# In Microsoft Visual Studio 2005 is it possible to set the size of an edit window when opened?

Tags: visual-c++

I have a very large monitor. When I open a text file in MSVC, the file defaults to a width of about 80% of my screen space. For most bits of code that's about twice the size I need. Is there a way to set the default size of a newly opened file?

Answer (score 1):

In the regular paned UI you can choose to split the code window horizontally or vertically, try that. You then get two code windows with each their own tab bar.